# SSRS: programmatically repopulate multi value parameter after execution

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS 2008 R2 report that is basically the front-end of a data extraction and manipulation process.

From the front-end the user can 'reload' the data from the various data sources, they can 'recalculate' the data which effectively pulls in some amended values and pushes all the data through a series of financial calculations or they can 'finalise' the data which basically moves the data from a staging schema into a fixed schema where the data persists as is.

Typically though the report will just be executed to see the current months data or a previous month's fixed data.

Should one of the 'reload', 'recalculate' or 'finalise' options be activated then upon completion when the report returns having rendered the data I'd like to be able to repopulate a multi-value parameter and reset the 'reload', 'recalculate' and 'finalise' parameters.  This is to prevent accidentally reloading the data twice in succession, for example.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I'd welcome feedback on what more information I can give to help get some answers...?

Comment: Are you updating the database when a user clicks 'reload'?  If you are tracking the state of the data set in the database, then you can use state information to write a query that populates the parameter with valid actions based on the current state.

Comment: Yes, the database is updated.  The process takes around 25 minutes to complete (third party procedure that I have no control over) and what I don't want is for the end-user to forget to reset 'reload' to false when they rerun the report as that will cause another 25 minutes wait unnecessarily...

Comment: Does the report refresh before the 25 minutes of processing are complete (the user just knows they need to wait 25 minutes before continuing), or does the user leave the SSRS page open for 25 minutes until the SSRS processing spinner is replaced with the report?

Comment: The report spins for 25 mins and then returns the freshly loaded data